# Running a simulation with n random numbers 100times vs running the simulation once with 100n random numbers?

Tags: sampling

For simplicity lets say,

I have a program that generates 50 random numbers and these 50 random numbers are put into a function that generates a single output.

Why would I want to repeat this experiment a 100times rather than just run a version with 5000 random numbers? What would be the advantages of doing so(if any)?

I am faintly aware of a method that repeats the process with a small number of randomly generated numbers a lot of times, but I can't seem to remember it.

Comment: Could you explain in what sense would it even be possible to shove 5000 numbers into a function that, by definition, accepts only 50 numbers as input?

Comment: @whuber I think it's clear from the question and esp. the question title.  There's no limit of 50 on the input variables.

Comment: Yeah 50 is just a random number I choose

Comment: @Rolando With experience comes the ability to imagine many more possibilities that comport with a vague or inconsistent description like the one in this question.  Since, then, "clarity" becomes a matter of personal opinion, we prefer to address only questions that do not suffer from such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 100 times, each time your statistical method gives you results (like p-value) for a sample size of 50
- once for 5000, your method gives you a result for a sample size of 5000

They are very different! Apple and Orange comparison.

In the former case, you're like doing bootstrapping. You get lot's of goodies like variance, confidence interval.

In the second case, you're just running a statistical method once. You might still be able to derive confidence interval, but only if you make further statistical assumptions.